# Blitz Cache dynamic button

Tags: templating, plugin-blitz

I have a Blitz Cache but the only bit of dynamic data on the page is a "Follow" button which changes depending on if you're following this entry. Looking at their docs, I don't see a way of not caching a certain section or button?

```
{% if craft.follow.check({ elementId: entry.id }) %}
    <span class="material-icons mr-2 md-18">favorite</span>Remove Brand</a>
{% else %}
    <span class="material-icons mr-2 md-18">favorite_border</span>Save Brand</a>
{% endif %}
```

Is it possible to still make this dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out "Dynamic Content" in the "Advanced Usage" section of the Blitz docs:
https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/blitz#dynamic-content

Thus can be done with:

```
{{ craft.blitz.getTemplate('/template/name', { elementId: entry.id }) }}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for this. I'll get to creating a partial with this in.